# How to split a dashed line into separate elements in Inkscape

Tags: inkscape

I have a dashed line in Inkscape. I want to change this so each dash is a separate object. How do I do that? The operation is similar to [this one](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/685909) in Adobe Illustrator. I'm trying to do the same thing with Inkscape.

Comment: Please update your question with what you've already tried and if you encountered any specific issues. You're likely to get better answers if you show that you've put some effort into doing your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two ways I can think to do this:

- Convert the stroke to a path and then break it apart.
- Create a duplicate path and use it to cut up another

## Converting stroke to path

1. Select the path.
2. On the **Path** menu, click **Stroke to Path**
3. With the path still selected, on the **Path** menu, click **Break Apart**

This will essentially create small rectangles rather than signular 2-node paths.

## Using a path to cut another

If you need two-node paths, do the following.

1. Select the path.
2. Change the path to solid stroke (not dashes)
3. On the **Edit** menu, click **Duplicate**.
   This will create a duplicate path on top of the existing path.
4. Select the top path only
5. Change the stroke to dashes
6. With the top path still selected, on the **Path** menu, click **Stroke to Path**
7. Select both paths.
8. On the **Path** menu, click **Cut Path**.

You will now have one path, but you'll have nodes where the dashes were. You'll need to use the Node Tool <kbd>F2</kbd>to individually select and delete segments between nodes to create the dashes.

Answer (score 3):

Inkscape also includes an extension which converts dash patterns into sub-paths:

- Extensions > Modify Path > [Convert to Dashes](http://tavmjong.free.fr/INKSCAPE/MANUAL/html/Extensions-ModifyPath.html#Extensions-ConvertToDashes)

These sub-paths can then be split into individual paths with `Path > Break apart` if needed.

The advantage over `Stroke to Path` and `Break apart`: it does not outline the stroke - the geometry of the (sub-)paths is still defined by their center-line.